# JBOSS 7.1 avoid logging certain classes log

Tags: java, logging, struts2, log4j, jboss7.x

First of all, I wanted to apologize for my english.

We are trying to avoid writing messages from a third party library into the server.log file (JBOSS 7.1). The class from the 3rd party library (org.apache.struts2.util.TextProviderHelper) writes the logs as follows:

`LOG.warn("The default value expression '"+defaultMessage+"' evaluated to '"+msg+"'");`

In order to achieve what we are looking for, we have configured the *log4j.properties* from our application as follows:

`log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2.util.TextProviderHelper=ERROR,SgaGstsystem 
 log4j.additivity.org.apache.struts2.util.TextProviderHelper=false`

This evicts printing the warning message in the application log but, as far as the logging level in the *standalone.xml* file from the JBOSS server is set to *WARN*, that message appears in the server.log file.

We wanted to know if there is any solution to avoid writing that message into the *server.log* file without having to modify the standalone.xml configuration file? (log4j.properties configuration, Logging filters,...)

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Thank you for your help Roman, but this is not the same question as the one you marked as the exact duplicate.
As you can see in the code pasted in the question, we have already tried to configure the logs written by the different loggers, but the logger configured in JBOSS keeps on writing logs from the TextProviderHelper class.

Anyway, we tried your recommendation and did not work as we expected.